# Updating record entries via userform?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to procure code, which will allow a user to click on a command button and update their data within the table row of this userform. Say a user has a name change, or changes work location, they'd ideally be able to click a button and have the form come up with their data to change. I'm unsure where to go from here, but this is what I have so far. I want the user to be able to type in their employee ID (EmplID) and then a form pops up with their info so that they can change it and resubmit it.

UPDATED CODE BASED ON KARMA'S RESPONSE

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim EmplID As String
Dim CLoc As Range
    
Set ws = Worksheets("Data")
    
    EmplID = InputBox("Enter Employee ID")
    
    Set CLoc = ws.Columns("C:C").Find(What:=EmplID, After:=ws.Cells(3), LookIn:= _
                            xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:= _
                               xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If CLoc Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "There is no ID found": Exit Sub
    Else
        CLoc.Select 'remove this line as this line is only for showing the found ID cell
        iRow = CLoc.Row
    End If
    
Me.txtFirstName.Value = ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value
Me.txtLastName.Value = ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value
Me.txtPersonNumber.Value = ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value
Me.txtLocation.Value = ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value
Me.txtEmail.Value = ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value

End Sub
Private Sub Update_Entry_Click()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Data")
    ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.txtFirstName.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.txtLastName.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.txtPersonNumber.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.txtLocation.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.txtEmail.Value
End Sub
```

Update: Getting an application/object defined error on this line after i pull up the entry and try to update the rows data:

`ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.txtFirstName.Value`

Comment: Can you be more specific than "isn't working"?

Comment: @BigBen when i click the button, nothing happens.

Comment: @bigben when the user clicks the button, I'd like their info to be populated in the userform that I've made in order for them to update whatever info needs updating

Comment: Add some `Debug.Print`s . It'll be easier to do some debugging on your end.

Comment: @BigBen I'm unsure where I should be placing them?

Comment: I think you need to put the code in another sub (another button) to populate your text boxes based on the found EmpID input in sheet row without `ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.txtFirstName.Value` etc lines (without the last four lines before End Sub). Put the `Dim` before any sub. For example, in another sub you have : input box, the find process, the if process, then something like this line : `Me.txtFirstName.Value = ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value` and so on. In `Private Sub Update_Entry_Click()` just have that last four lines (`ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.txtFirstName.Value`, and so on)

Comment: @karma sorry, not sure I'm following. how does that differ than what i already have?

Comment: With the one with you already have, it doesn't populate the listbox and you can't put the code to populate the textbox in the same sub with the update cell in the sheet based on the textbox value. So, with another button you'll have this `Me.txtFirstName.Value = ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value` line. This line tell the code to fill the value of txtFirstName textbox based on the ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value. Then in your existing Update_Entry button, the macro is on the other way `ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.txtFirstName.Value`, this tell the code to fill ws.Cells(iRow, 1) with txtFirstName textbox value.

Comment: In other words, the first button is to display the data in the sheet in the user form after the user input his ID. Say for example the txtLocation textbox in the userform now has "West" text after the user input his ID. Then the user change the textbox value from "West" to "North". Then he click the second button to update the cell in the sheet.

Comment: In other words, the first button is to display the data in the sheet into the textbox in the user form after the user input his ID. Say for example the txtLocation textbox in the userform now has "West" text after the user input his ID. Then the user change the textbox value from "West" to "North". Then he click the second button to update the cell in the sheet.

Comment: ok i think i get what you mean. i can utilize that `me.txt...` line in another sub based on the input box entry, and then have that update?

Comment: @karma so I swapped it to populate the rows data into the text boxes, but how would I have the code actually overwrite it? I already have an `add entry` button, which does what i want to do, but i want it to overwrite the record instead of just place another one in the table

Comment: @NidenK, please have a look to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an example code :

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim iRow As Long

Private Sub IDdescription_Click()
Set ws = Sheets("Data")
EmplID = ID.Value

    Set CLoc = ws.Columns("C:C").Find(What:=EmplID, After:=ws.Cells(3), LookIn:= _
                            xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:= _
                               xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If CLoc Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "There is no ID found": Exit Sub
        'iRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 3) _
               .End(xlUp).Offset(1, 3).Row
    Else
        CLoc.Select 'remove this line as this line is only for showing the found ID cell
        iRow = CLoc.Row
    End If
    
Me.txtFirstName.Value = ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value
Me.txtLastName.Value = ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value
Me.txtLocation.Value = ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value
Me.txtEmail.Value = ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value
End Sub

Private Sub Update_Entry_Click()
    ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.txtFirstName.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.txtLastName.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.txtLocation.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.txtEmail.Value
End Sub
```

The "See ID description" button name is IDdescription

[image]

Comment: Hey i updated my code to your response, it's nearly working but getting an application defined error on this line: `ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.txtFirstName.Value`

Comment: @NidenK, maybe it's because there is no value for iRow. And sorry I don't understand why you put the dim on each sub, while the test Sub in my post put the dim at the top before any sub as I've mentioned it in my comment before. Try to put the dim at the top and no dim at any sub just like the test Sub example.

Comment: the dim is there because the option explicit is preventing the code from executing because they're all private subs.

Comment: also, I hover over `iRow` and it says 0, so it's clearly not actually searching through. Could this be because the CLoc isn't in the sub?

Comment: sorry, it's working great now, thanks so much for all of your guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reinventing the wheel. If your on o365, you can enable "Forms" in excel. This will automatically create a user form.

Check this link - [Create User form](https://trumpexcel.com/data-entry-form/)

Comment: unsure how this will populate what i need? I already have a userform built out